Regex to match optional prefix ending with a specific character
My regex (\d\dX) should match two digits followed by a specific character X.
Any number of optional characters are allowed to precede it provided it ends with a + character.
For Example:

12X is valid
ABC+22X is valid
ABC+123X is not valid.

I came up with the following regex But this does not work as expected.
(.*\+)*(\d\dX)

.* any number of characters
\+ indicates the character +
(.*\+)* indicates any number of previous occurrence.
(\d\dX) match two digits followed by X
What am I doing wrong ? I tried various combinations of regex without success.

What about ABC+12XX which has a trailing character after the 12X.  Providing more examples of valid and invalid strings would help.  And how are you matching using Java?  Some of the posted answers won't work properly if using String.matches.

Your (.*\+)* is an optional pattern, it matches zero or more occurrences of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then +.
You may use
(?<=\+|^)(\d\d)X
(?<=\+|^)\d\d(?=X)

See the regex demo.
Details:

(?<=\+|^) - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with + or at the start of string
(\d\d)X - two digits captured into Group 1 and then X
\d\d(?=X) - two digits that are immediately followed with an X character ((?=X) is a positive lookahead here).


Wow, a working answer within 5 minutes :) . I was banging my head for more than 50 minutes. Running my tests against the expression. Initial cases work. Let me check further and will accept your answer.

If finding 1 match is enough, you can make the part ending on a plus sigh before the 2 digits optional and start the pattern with an anchor:
^(?:.*\+)?(\d\d)X

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
(?:.*\+)? Optionally match any character ending on +
(\d\d) Capture 2 digits
X Match literally

See a regex demo.

Try the below regex:
(?:.*\+)?\d{2}X$


That will have a partial match in ABC+123X which it should not according to the question. See https://regex101.com/r/MzXDNj/1
